# Laravel Error: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

Good evening , for school i am trying to create a simple CRUD app, using laravel 6 and mongoDB.

I can get read, update and delete working but creat fails with The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.. I have searched the answers here and other sites but im stuck for 2 days now (could be something very silly but im not seeing it)

my routes are:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/post/{_id?}', 'PostController@form')->name('post.form');
Route::post('/post/save/', 'PostController@save')->name('post.save');
Route::put('/post/update/{_id}', 'PostController@update')->name('post.update');
Route::get('/post/delete/{_id}', 'PostController@delete')->name('post.delete');
```

form.blade is:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Post Form</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @if($data)
                <form action = "{{Route ('post.update', $data->_id)}}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    @method('PUT')
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="usr">Title:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value = "{{$data->title}}" >
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comment">Content:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="content">{{$data->content}}</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <p align="center"> <button class="btn btn-primary">save</button></p>
                </form>

                @else
                <form action = "{{Route ('post.form')}}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="usr">Title:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comment">Content:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="content"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <p align="center"> <button class="btn btn-primary">save</button></p>
                </form>

                @endif

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

and my PostController is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function form($_id = false){
        if($_id){
            $data = Post::findOrFail($_id);

        }

       $data = false;
        return view ('post.form', compact('data'));
    }

    public function save (Request $request){
    $data =  new Post($request->all());

    $data->save();

    if($data){
        return redirect()->route('home');

    }else{
        return back();
        }
    }

    public function update (Request $request, $_id){

        $data = post::findOrFail($_id);

        $data->title    = $request->title;
        $data->content  = $request->content;
        $data->save();

        /* return response()->json([
            'name' => 'Abigail',
            'state' => 'CA'
        ]); */

        if($data){
            return redirect()->route('home');

        }else{
            return back();
            }
        }

        public function delete($_id){
            $data = post::destroy($_id);
            if($data) {
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
         else {
            dd('error cannot delete this post');
        }
    }
}
```

Anybody any idea what i am missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to replace this line `<form action = "{{Route ('post.form')}}" method="post">` with `<form action = "{{Route ('post.save')}}" method="post">`

Comment: In addition it's also a good idea to switch the order the routes are declared because `post/{_id}` might match `post/save` and be picked up first

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong route. Please change to `Route ('post.save')`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I found that one myself, the PostControler didnt return a view if there was an $_id

Thanks for the help everyone!
Thanks for pointing that out, it did bring my from back to life :) However it breaks the update function :S.

When i now click on the edit button, the form does no longer get filled with the data for the post, and "save" creates a new post  in stead of updating it.